# undefined variable in codeigniter view which is already defined in the controller

Tags: codeigniter

This is my controller. here i declared current_company.

```
public function index($id='')
{   
    $this->load->model('Company_model');
    ($id!='') ? $data["company_details"]=$this->Company_model->get_company($id) :'';

($id!='') ? $data ["current_company"]=$this->Company_model->get_currentcomp($id) :'';

    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('includes/left_menu');
    $this->load->view('company/manage',($id!='') ? $data : '');
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

This is my model. Here i declared the function

```
class Company_model extends CI_Model{

     protected $strTableName = 'suc_company';
     function __construct(){

         parent::__construct ();
         $this->db->from($this->strTableName);
     }

     function get_currentcomp($intPkId){            

         $this->db->where('pk_bint_company_id',$intPkId);
         $q1 = $this->db->get($this->strTableName);            
         return $q1->result_array()[0];
     }
```

This is the view part. here i called the $current_company !== FALSE then

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="company_package" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Package</label>
     <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12"> 
         <?php if ($current_company !== FALSE ) {?>                                     
             <select name="company_package"  class="form-control select2" disabled="">
             <option value="<?php echo $company_package;?>" selected=""><?php echo $packagename;?></option>

             </select>
         <?php } else { ?>

         <?php } ?>
```

Error

> an error is occurring... undefined data current_company

Comment: change method name `index` to any other name

Comment: You have set `$data ["current_company"]` variable only when `$id` not equal to blank, If your id will blank in that case `$data ["current_company"]` is not initialise. that's why is throwing undefined error.

Comment: Not sure why you only have this `$this->db->from($this->strTableName);` in the construct area?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to compare $current_company to NULL instead of FALSE?

Comment: You are leaving possibility that `$data` wouldn't be passed to the view.

Answer (score 2):

Change your controller code like this.

```
public function index($id='')
{   
    $this->load->model('Company_model');

    $data["company_details"] = false;
    $data["current_company"] = false;

    if($id != ''){
        $data["company_details"] = $this->Company_model->get_company($id);
        $data["current_company"] = $this->Company_model->get_currentcomp($id);
    }

    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('includes/left_menu');
    $this->load->view('company/manage',$data);
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

Comment: Why initialise the values $data["company_details"] and friend to a boolean value? They are being used as strings... so why would you not initialise them to an empty string like $data["company_details"] = '';

Comment: Its because he compared boolean value in view file as you can see@TimBrownlaw

Comment: True, but PHP is a little (too) forgiving and treats a string as true and an empty string as false. This is interesting reading - http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment, you are leaving possibility that maybe $data wouldn't be passed to view file. You have to restrict this kind of oscillations. 
Try this way:

```
public function index($id='')
{   
    if ((int)$id < 1) {
        redirect('some/generic/place', 'refresh');
    }

    // we have integer in parameter
    // so we will check if data by that parameter exists

    $data = [];// initialization of array so we are sure $data is set

    $this->load->model('Company_model');

    $data['company_details'] = $this->Company_model->get_company($id);

    if ($data['company_details']) {
        $data['current_company'] = $this->Company_model->get_currentcomp($id) :'';
    } else {
        // in this point $data is an empty array
    }

    // $this way variable will be available in all view files
    $this->load->var($data);

    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('includes/left_menu');
    $this->load->view('company/manage');
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');

    // so now, in your view you would have wether company with details wether an empty array

    // *first line of code assumes parameter would be an integer
    // **also assumed that $this->Company_model->get_company($id) would return false/null/anEmptyArray if data doesn't exist
}
```